# tomcat 7, grails app, finding the running webapp?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I installed Tomcat 7 on CentOS 6 and everything is running good, is running as service, can start and stop it, log file looks fine.

BUT, it doesn't respond to my webapp address, so I've got something wrong ...

I'm able to access tomcat externally on: www.my-domain.us:8080 (standard welcome Apache Tomcat 7 page),  but when I try to access it under my application which is called cpn, I cannot.   I am trying:

```
www.my-domain.us:8080/cpn
www.my-domain.us/cpn
www.my-domain.us:8080/cpn/cpn
```

The cpn.war file was exploded properly by Tomcat in webapps, i.e. I have a

```
 .../webapps/cpn/* directory
```

In application.properties the app.name=cpn.

Also, in Config.groovy I have:

```
 grails.serverURL = "http://www.my-domain.us"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not responding at all then it probably didn't start up successfully, check the log files for "startup failed due to previous errors".  A common problem can be if Grails is trying to create its default `stacktrace.log` log file but the "current directory" whatever that is is not writable by the UID of the Tomcat process.  You can eliminate this as a possibility by adding

```
'null' name:'stacktrace'
```

to the `appenders` block in your `log4j` closure in `Config.groovy` to turn off `stacktrace.log` altogether.

Also if your Tomcat is visible at `www.my-domain.us:8080` then your `grails.serverURL` should be `http://www.my-domain.us:8080/cpn`, i.e. it should *in*clude the webapp context path as well as the host name and port number and should *not* end with a slash.

If you want the app to be deployed at the root context (`http://www.my-domain.us:8080/`) then you should name it `ROOT.war` instead of `cpn.war` and set `grails.serverURL="http://www.my-domain.us:8080"`

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'm going to look, where should I best configure the port to the standard 80?   Per an installation example I did change ownership for the tomcat directory to user "tomcat"

Comment: @Ray I wouldn't put Tomcat itself on port 80, because that would require running it as root.  What I usually do is put the Tomcat running on 8080 behind a "reverse proxy" (Apache HTTPD or Nginx) running on 80.  There's plenty of examples on the web of how to set this up.

Comment: And your right, I do want it without any "cpn" app-name, just at root.  I'm going to try that now too (well, tried it before but was lower case root.war, not ROOT.war).  Will try again.

Comment: I'm going to need SSL too - have a certificate.  Does this factor in in the reverse proxy?   Unfortunately I tried to get SSL running on Jetty 9 and just couldn't (my last question, no one responded as of yet).

Comment: @Ray yes, with the reverse proxy it's Apache (or Nginx) that handles the SSL and then talks to the Tomcat backend using plain HTTP.  You need to configure the Tomcat-side `<Connector>` with `scheme="https" secure="true"` (so it reports to the webapp that the connection is secure) but _don't_ set `SSLEnabled="true"` or the keystore-related options, because Tomcat is not doing SSL itself.

Comment: Does the Grails grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
'/cert/cpnimember': 'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL',
'/cert/page1': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',  etc.  <---- does this work with Apache though?   Doesn't the application container need to switch to SSL the way Grails is setup?   I'm using the common plugin: spring-security-core to setup the channels requiring SSL.

Comment: @Ray now you're getting complicated :-).  If you want both SSL and non-SSL then you need two connectors at the Tomcat side, both plain HTTP, one (say 8081) configured `scheme="https" secure="true"` and the other (8080) not.  Configure the front end proxy to pass port 80 through to 8080 and port 443 to 8081, again handling the actual SSL in the front end (and firewall off 8080 and 8081 so they can't be accessed directly without going through the proxy).

Comment: Maybe I should run everything SSL, but is that quite a bit slower?